# Blurry output to projector

Tags: display, displayport, vga-adapter, projector

I've connected a high-resolution projector to my MacBook Pro Retina through an Apple Mini DisplayPort-VGA adapter. It gets quite blurry (even for fonts) on the projector.  Here are the settings.

[image]

How do I make slides on the projector as clear as on the laptop?

Comment: Have you confirmed that the projector is in focus?

Comment: @Allan, thx for ur response. I didn't check it as I supposed it is the problem of my laptop. Now, I connect my macbook to a 28in display. The problem still exists.

Comment: VGA resolution is nowhere near Retina.  Can you connect via HDMI or other higher resolution adapter?

Comment: @bjbk, the projector of my lab only offers VGA connection:-(